# How to create an IBInspectable of type enum

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

`enum` is **not** an Interface Builder defined runtime attribute.
The following does not show in Interface Builder's Attributes Inspector:

```
enum StatusShape:Int {
    case Rectangle = 0
    case Triangle = 1
    case Circle = 2
}
@IBInspectable var shape:StatusShape = .Rectangle
```

From the documentation:
*You can attach the IBInspectable attribute to any property in a class declaration, class extension, or category for any type that’s supported by the Interface Builder defined runtime attributes: boolean, integer or floating point number, string, localized string, rectangle, point, size, color, range, and nil.*

**Q:** How can I see an `enum` in  Interface Builder's Attributes Inspector?

Comment: Where is enum in that list? Why would you think you can use an enum?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to pick an `enum` case straight from IB I suppose, or a `UIFont`, like the native UIKit objects can.

Answer (score 83):

## Swift 3

**@IBInspectable** `var shape:StatusShape = .Rectangle` merely creates a blank entry in Interface Builder:

[image: Not available in IB]

Use an adapter, which will acts as a **bridge** between Swift and Interface Builder.
`shapeAdapter` is inspectable from IB:

```
   // IB: use the adapter
   @IBInspectable var shapeAdapter:Int {
        get {
            return self.shape.rawValue
        }
        set( shapeIndex) {
            self.shape = StatusShape(rawValue: shapeIndex) ?? .Rectangle
        }
    }
```

[image: Available in IB]

Unlike the conditional compilation approach (using `#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER`), the type of the `shape` variable does not change with the target, potentially requiring further source code changes to cope with the `shape:NSInteger` vs. `shape:StatusShape` variations:

```
   // Programmatically: use the enum
   var shape:StatusShape = .Rectangle
```

#### Complete code

```
@IBDesignable
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum StatusShape:Int {
        case Rectangle
        case Triangle
        case Circle
    }

    // Programmatically: use the enum
    var shape:StatusShape = .Rectangle

    // IB: use the adapter
    @IBInspectable var shapeAdapter:Int {
        get {
            return self.shape.rawValue
        }
        set( shapeIndex) {
            self.shape = StatusShape(rawValue: shapeIndex) ?? .Rectangle
        }
    }
}
```

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-27432736).

Comment: Why are you keeping `shapeAsInt` as a stored property rather than a computed property?

Comment: Right.  You can't make a property `writeonly` though... but a computed property doesn't create a backing instance variable like your stored property does.

Comment: Added a *no backing store* solution proposed by @nhgrif.

Comment: Excuse my downvote. I thought I had a working solution with TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER but I was misled. Sorry, best of luck here on SO

Comment: fast forward to 2017 does this issue still remain the same?

Comment: I was searching if it was possible to use enums or an array etc. However all I can find is information from 2015 or before so I was wondering if in 2017 with xcode 8.2.1 it is still the same as it was 2 years or so ago

Comment: No, still a relevant solution as of Xcode 8.2.1. See `ViewController.swift` _line 37_ on https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-27432736: `shape` **is** `@IBInspectable` yet not visible in **IB**

Answer (score 44):

Instead of setting your inspectable enums with ints, you could also set them with strings.  Although not quite as preferable as a dropdown, at least this option offers some level of readability.

**Swift-only Option:**

```
// 1. Set up your enum
enum Shape: String {
    case Rectangle = "rectangle" // lowercase to make it case-insensitive
    case Triangle = "triangle"
    case Circle = "circle"
}


// 2. Then set up a stored property, which will be for use in code
var shape = Shape.Rectangle // default shape


// 3. And another stored property which will only be accessible in IB (because the "unavailable" attribute prevents its use in code)
@available(*, unavailable, message: "This property is reserved for Interface Builder. Use 'shape' instead.")
@IBInspectable var shapeName: String? {
    willSet {
        // Ensure user enters a valid shape while making it lowercase.
        // Ignore input if not valid.
        if let newShape = Shape(rawValue: newValue?.lowercased() ?? "") {
            shape = newShape
        }
    }
}
```

It *is* possible to also get this to work with objective-c as well, by adding an initializer to the enum. However, the compiler will only show the "unavailable" error for your IB-only properties in swift code.

**Swift Option with Obj-C Compatibility:**

```
@objc enum Shape: Int {
    case None
    case Rectangle
    case Triangle
    case Circle

    init(named shapeName: String) {
        switch shapeName.lowercased() {
        case "rectangle": self = .Rectangle
        case "triangle": self = .Triangle
        case "circle": self = .Circle
        default: self = .None
        }
    }
}

var shape = Shape.Rectangle // default shape

@available(*, unavailable, message: "This property is reserved for Interface Builder. Use 'shape' instead.")
@IBInspectable var shapeName: String? {
    willSet {
        if let newShape = Shape(rawValue: newValue?.lowercased() ?? "") {
            shape = newShape
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the `Swift Only` version: it allows for plain English in **IB**.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the options presented as a dropdown of strings in IB using this method?

Comment: I would like to know if possible how to get this done using a dropdown please.

Answer (score 19):

I can't remember the swift syntax, but this is how I solved it in obj-c

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSInteger shape;
#else
@property (nonatomic) StatusShape shape;
#endif
```

Comment: The only place that I have the conditional assembly is that one spot in the declaration. No conditional assembly anywhere else since an enum is an integer value in obj-c. One spot to remove when apple fixes this (assuming that they will.)

Comment: This is a witty and awesome solution, and mentioned here http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Answer (score 7):

## For 2020 - @SwiftArchitect answer updated for today:

Here's a typical full example with all of today's syntax

[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ClipLabels: UILabel {
    
    enum Side: Int { case left, right }
    
    var side: Side = .left {
        didSet {
            common()
        }
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable, message: "IB only")
    @IBInspectable var leftRight01: Int {
        get {
            return self.side.rawValue
        }
        set(index) {
            self.side = Side(rawValue: index) ?? .left
        }
    }
```

and just an example of use ...

```
switch side {
    case .left:
        textColor = .red
    case .right:
        textColor = .green
    }
```

For this critical Swift/iOS QA,

• the very old answer of @SwiftArchitect is perfectly correct but

• I've just updated it and added the critical "unavailable" thing, which is now possible in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread but useful. I have adapted my answer to swift 4.0 and Xcode 9.0 - Swift 4 has its own little issues with this problem. I am having an @IBInspectable variable with enum type and Xcode 9.0 is not happy, showing me this "Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be representing in Objective-c"

@Eporediese answers this problem (for swift3) in part; using a property for the storyboard but a straight enum for the rest of the code. Below is a more complete code set that gives you a property to work with in both cases.

```
enum StatusShape: Int {
  case Rectangle = 0
  case Triangle = 1
  case Circle = 2
}
var _shape:StatusShape = .Rectangle  // this is the backing variable

#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
  @IBInspectable var shape: Int {    // using backing variable as a raw int

    get { return _shape.rawValue }
    set {
      if _shape.rawValue != newValue {
        _shape.rawValue = newValue
      }
    }
}
#else
var shape: StatusShape {  // using backing variable as a typed enum
  get { return _shape }
  set {
    if _shape != newValue {
      _shape = newValue
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**
solution based on [SwiftArchitect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27435318/1415703)

```swift
enum StatusShape: Int {
    case rectangle, triangle, circle
}
var statusShape: StatusShape = .rectangle
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
@IBInspectable var statusShapeIB: Int {
    get { 
        return statusShape.rawValue 
    }
    set { 
        guard let statusShape = StatusShape(rawValue: newValue) else { return }
        self.statusShape = statusShape
    }
}   //convenience var, enum not inspectable
#endif
```

Comment: If you wrap this IB-inspectable property in a `#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` block it will only affect the rendering in Interface Builder, not at run time. This will likely result in unexpected behavior and you'll always get a warning in the console: `Failed to set (statusShapeIB) user defined inspected property ...: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key statusShapeIB.`