# Add a custom palette to IB that propagates if a color changes iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to create a custom palette in IB where you can set colors, and if a color changes in that palette it propagates through the views. I've seen this approach http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-color-palette/, but if in the future, a color of the palette changes, you have to go to every view on the project and change that color. I tried also doing an @IBInspectable but you can't have enums (so you can map an enum to a color). I know i can just define the colors by code and then having an outlet, but the problem is I a have tons of views that I need to subclass just for changing a color like this:

```
class TestCommonView: CommonView {
@IBOutlet weak var borderView: UIView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        borderView.backgroundColor = Colors.fabrica.pastel
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Writing random strings doesnt look good to me...

Comment: @SwiftArchitect it looks promising... I have to put it into a little project and check if it passes the acid test. I mean, once I change a value in the enum's definition, and run it again, the new value should be reflected on runtime.

Comment: I suggest to use `@IBInspectable` as a mere starting point, and tie in with an `@IB_Designable` to show the color on the fly. You would rely on the adapter to put either `Int` or `String` in **IB**, and your **Swift** `Extension` should convert that into an actual color. That color, in turn, can be read and displayed right into **IB**.

Answer (score 2):

*Reconsidering this statement:*

> I tried also doing an @IBInspectable but you can't have enums (so you can map an enum to a color).

You can bridge over an `@IBInspectable` `enum` using `Int` this way:

```
enum ColorPalette:Int {
    case clear = 0
    case teal = 1
    case plum = 2
    case foam = 3
}
var tincture:ColorPalette = .clear
```

In **code**, access `self.tincture`, which is the `enum` you are after.
In **Interface Builder**, use `tinctureAdapter` which is an `Int`, and therefore a de-facto `@IBInspectable` of type enum.

```
// Stored IB property
@available(*, unavailable, message="Use tincture programmatically")
@IBInspectable var tinctureAdapter:Int {
    get {
        return self.tincture.rawValue
    }
    set {
        self.tincture = ColorPalette:Int(rawValue: newValue) ?? .clear
    }
}
```

It may be useful to place this code in a `UIColor` class Extension. Using the bridge approach, you could also use *@Donamite* [plain-English](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32193340/218152) strings in **IB**.

---

**Swift 3 Example**

```
@IBDesignable class ColorSwatchView: UIView {

    enum ColorPalette: String {
        case Thistle    = "thistle"
        case Plum       = "plum"
        case Olive      = "olive"
        case Iris       = "iris"

        case Clear      = "clear"
    }

    let namedColors = [
        "thistle": UIColor(red: 216/255, green: 191/255, blue: 216/255, alpha: 1),
        "plum"   : UIColor(red: 221/255, green: 160/255, blue: 221/255, alpha: 1),
        "olive"  : UIColor(red: 128/255, green: 128/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1),
        "iris"   : UIColor(red: 3/255, green: 180/255, blue: 200/255, alpha: 1)
    ]

    var tincture:ColorPalette = .Clear

    // Stored IB property
    @available(*, unavailable, message: "Use tincture programmatically")
    @IBInspectable var tinctureName: String? {
        willSet {
            if let color = ColorPalette(rawValue: newValue?.lowercased() ?? "") {
                tincture = color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface Builder**

*Make your custom view a child of `ColorSwatchView`*.

[image]

**Programmatically**

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    ctx?.saveGState()
    let uiColor = namedColors[tincture.rawValue] ?? UIColor.clear
    ctx?.setFillColor(uiColor.cgColor)
    ctx?.fill(bounds)
    ctx?.restoreGState()
}
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-31702193) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-31702193).

Comment: I think this is a correct answer. Personally I've done similar thing in my project

Comment: Until Apple comes up with support, this is the best we have. I'm surprised `Color` and `enum` were not added in Xcode 7, alonside **Swift 2.0**