# IBInspectable Properties not showing up in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ibinspectable

While attempting to modify the Apple tutorial found [here on IBinspectable](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html) properties for my own project I have run into a major roadblock.

I defined a simple button subclass:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable public class SocialMediaLoginButton: UIButton {

  private var _loginType: SocialMediaLoginType = .facebook

  @IBInspectable public var loginType: SocialMediaLoginType 
              = SocialMediaLoginType.facebook {

      didSet {
          self._loginType = loginType
      }
  }
}
```

And then added a UIButton to my storyboard which I then selected the CustomClass as the above type. When I switch over to the Attributes inspector the property is not there for me to adjust. I have no idea what is going on:

[image: Attributes inspector]

I have looked up other questions however there are either extremely outdated or have no answers on the app developer forum.

I have tried:

1. Manually refreshing the views
2. closing and reopening xcode
3. removing and re-adding the control
4. adding different controls like UIView and attempting same thing

None of these have worked. I am at a loss for how to fix this. I am using Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432736/how-to-create-an-ibinspectable-of-type-enum

Comment: Thank you I just found that. So I am just stuck with either a bunch of bools, magic strings, or opaque numbers.

Answer (score 9):

Interface Builder supports the inspection of basic types (and their corresponding optionals), including: Booleans, numbers, strings, as well as CGRect, CGSize, CGPoint, and UIColor.

I think your type does not work with interface builder.

Answer (score 8):

To add to Wilson answer, you MUST EXPLICITLY specify the type (Int, String, etc.) for it to show.

Comment: I had this problem. For example, `@IBInspectable var lineWidth = CGFloat(2.0)` will **not** work; you have to be explicit: `@IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2.0`.