# Property @IBInspectable cannot be marked

Tags: swift, swift4

how to fix this problem, after installing xcode 9 show me this

"Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be representing in Objective-c"

```
/// The mode of the gradient. The default is `.Linear`.
@IBInspectable open var mode: Mode = .linear {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/// The direction of the gradient. Only valid for the `Mode.Linear` mode. The default is `.Vertical`.
@IBInspectable open var direction: Direction = .vertical {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an IBInspectable of type enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432736/how-to-create-an-ibinspectable-of-type-enum)

Comment: Please edit your question to include code formatted as text using proper code formatting. Never include code as a screenshot in your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I edited.

Comment: Adding @objc in front of enum does silent the warning but does not make the property to show up in Attribute Inspector or User Defined Runtime Attributes in Identity Inspector. Instead I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432736/how-to-create-an-ibinspectable-of-type-enum/46738871#46738871 
to help solve the issue. It still is an issue in Swift 4.0/xcode 9. I also added my answer for backing variable (if needed inside the class for other computations).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add @objc for the enum:

```
@objc public enum Mode: Int {
        ...
}

@objc public enum Direction: Int {
        ...
}
```

You do need the `Int` base type, that can't be "blank" if it is an `@objc` style.

Comment: But the var property 'mode' ( of type 'objc enum Mode' ) is still Not present in the "Attributes inspector" in the "Interface Builder".

Comment: Because IB does not support enums even for ObjC :(