# Swift keyboard selection from @IBInspectable

Tags: swift, textfield

I am using keyboard selection in Swift for textfields and I need to show enum name (emailAdress...) in @IBInspectable instead of its Int number (0-6). How can I fix this?

```
  public class TextFieldView: UIView{

     enum KeyboardType: Int {
            case normal
            case asciiCapable
            case numberPad
            case phonePad
            case emailAddress
            case namePhonePad
        }

      @IBInspectable public var keyBoard: Int = 0 {
            didSet {
                let keyBoardType = KeyboardType(rawValue: keyBoard)
                self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.init(rawValue: keyBoardType!.rawValue)!

            }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an IBInspectable of type enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432736/how-to-create-an-ibinspectable-of-type-enum)

Answer (score 0):

use **CustomStringConvertible**

```
enum KeyboardType: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
     case normal = 0
     case asciiCapable = 1
     case numberPad = 2
          ...

     var description: String {
          switch self {
       case .normal:
          return "normal"
       case .asciiCapable:
          return "asciiCapable"
           ...
          }
    }
```